# Custom actions and references to widgets with FlutterFlow

Tags: flutterflow

I have a Button widget and a RichText widget in FlutterFlow. How can I get in a custom action for the Button widget a reference to the RichText widget in order to change its properties?

Comment: Can you please explain in details with exact scenario?